Setting object values to ng-model in angularjs
I am using angularjs 1st version to display values on multiple text fields using ng-model.
I have an object like this


$scope.fieldValues = {
   keys: Object.keys(subkeys),
   values: Object.values(subkeys)
 }



my div:


<div ng-repeat="">
  <div class="">
    <input type="text" name="{{field.name}}" ng-model="fieldValues.values" required />
  </div>
</div>



Please help me in setting the object values in the text field using ng-model.

Can you describe the logic? How do you want to set multiple values with one single text input? fieldValues.values is an array.

how about use map first.
$scope.fieldValues = Object.entries($scope.subkeys).map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));

then use repeat your field values
<div ng-repeat="field in fieldValues">
  <div class="">
    <label>{{ field.key }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{ field.key }}" ng-model="subkeys[field.key]" required />
  </div>
</div>

